# Chrome touch ups?

Tags: repair, paint, metal

I have several chromed items where small amounts of the chrome has chipped off, leaving bare metal showing.  None of it is in prominent areas, so I just want to touch them up.  I haven't had luck with chrome spray paints in the past, as they never end up looking like chrome.  Is there some paint, marker, or whatever that actually looks like chrome?  I'm not looking for perfection, but passable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going to [Michael's](https://www.michaels.com/), a chain arts & crafts store, hobby store.  While I didnt see chrome, I picked up an [Extra Fine Tip Multi-Surface Premium Paint Pen by Craft Smart](https://www.michaels.com/extra-fine-tip-multisurface-premium-paint-pen-by-craft-smart/10426713.html) in metallic silver.  It actually worked very well.  I was able to cover the bare spots, which were very small and hidden.  Unless you were looking for it, you wouldnt spot the touched up areas.  Additionally, the fine tip made it easy to use.  Spray paint would have been a pain.

Comment: FYI, I used this paint pen on a few other bare spots on some chrome items.  I recently was told about some higher quality paint markers that have really good chrome paint, but they are far more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Paints have improved quite a bit over the years and quality plays a big role too. This paint provides good results

Krylon K01010A07 Premium Metalic Original Chrome

[image]